# Wordpress : How to set image source while creating page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

how can i set image url in page ?

[image]

In image you can see I have tried by three ways but it not work.

Images are located under image folder of active theme.

Comment: Why my question is down voted? Please give me reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows `<img src="../images/banner1.jpg" alt="">`

Comment: I tried also that one. but when I checked page source then it showing as I created `<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/banner1.jpg>` . it seems php code not print out the url.

Answer (score 0):

You have three image tags all pointing to different urls of which two appear malformed.

The middle image tag in your screenshot seems the most accurate but you may want to add a semicolon after the right paranthesis.

If all three files are supposed to refer to the same image, then replace the first and last image tags with the middle one.

Then if it still doesnt work then replace bloginfo('template_directory') with the actual location to the images relative to document root on the server but put the value in quotes. For example, if your images are in the subfolder images in folder imageset on your site, then you could use

```
"http://www.whatever.com/imageset/images" or "/imageset/images".
```

which results in the code:

```
<img src="<?php echo "/imageset/images"; ?>/images/banner1.jpg" alt="">
```

or even better:

```
<img src="/imageset/images/images/banner1.jpg" alt="">
```

Comment: How can I get template directory address ?

Comment: First find out the php files your document you're working on needs then look for the function named bloginfo then inside of it, look for something named template_directory. That's the basic idea (since I understand PHP) but since I haven't worked with the theme in question, I won't know exactly the operation of the function.